# HashMap synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, synchronized

I have a task to synchronize method `put(K key, V value)` of `HashMap`. But It should work faster then `synchronized(this)` or `synchronized(table)`. I wrote this code:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key == null) 
        return putForNullKey(value);

    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);

    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            synchronized(e) {
                V oldValue = e.value;
                e.value = value;
                e.recordAccess(this);
                return oldValue;
            }
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that when I call this method by different Threads using the same key, there can be situation, that `map.entrySet().size() > 1`. So my synchronization is wrong, but I don't understand why. How can I do this properly?

Comment: Like.. [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)?

Comment: I can't use it. It is a kind of educational task. A have to sinchronize common HashMap but it should work faster than Collections.synchronizedMap(hashMap);

Comment: What do you mean by "situation, that map.entrySet().size() > 1" and "synchronization is wrong", can you give details or examples?

Comment: If `table.length` is not changing (the standard `HashMap` does change that), then synchronizing access per bucket (not just entry) will allow multiple threads to add / read from different buckets at the same time. That would be a big improvement over locking the entire table since "good" (correctly sized, objects with evenly distributes hash values, ..) hashtables will not use the same bucket more than once or worst case a few times. Or lock smaller regions (called stripe locking AFAIK) of your buckets.

Comment: Since it is an educational task. Maybe you prof is not even aware about the complexisity of his question. Pls provide the solution of your mentor than. I am really interested in.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that when I call this method by different Threads using the same key, there can be situation, that map.entrySet().size() > 1. So my synchronization is wrong, but I don't understand why.

I'm not 100% sure I understand the error case, but I see a number of problems with your attempt at synchronization that will cause race conditions.

For example, if two threads try to add the same key to the `HashMap` at the same time, they are going to loop through the bucket and not find the entry.  Then both of them are going to try to add the entry to the table.  This could result in two entries with the same key or even corruption of the table.

I'm also assuming that `addEntry(...)` could change the bucket array which could cause rehashing of all of the elements.  So one thread could cause the buckets to change while another thread is working with an out-of-date array.  This could cause entries to be lost or again table corruption.

> How can I do this properly?

This is a non-trivial exercise.  One thing you could do is use a `ReadWriteLock` so at least you can have lookups not block the writing.  But if you are writing a new entry into the map, you may have to have an exclusive lock on it because of the changes to the bucket array mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Because your e can change before it enters the synchroniezed block,
The complete table can change before and during the iteration of the synchronized block.

The problem is to lock the table entries.
So maybe its better to declare the complete method as synchronized.

Work with semaphores (See Java concurrency API) to ensure atomic access to your table.

Update due to comment:

Provide a cache mechanism for your application. Introduce an additional list(queue, cache)
which gathers all incoming changes to your tables or map while they are blocked.
So your application can still proceed. Until the table is not blocked any more you
add the cache entries to you table.

An answer but just a suggestion.

Comment: Though you've identified the problem, the solution of synchronizing the method would slow things down and OP is looking for a faster solution.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis thats a faster solution i think. At least a guess for a solution.

Comment: We should always try to synchronize only around the critical section. Synchronizing on the whole method may cause more bottlenecks.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis. Do you have an optimal solution for this problem. I think its quite difficult. And also difficult to proof if it is really faster since there is no possibility to check the suggestion

Comment: I don't have a solution and you are correct, it'll be extremely hard to test.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that your `for` loop is iterating over a potentially changing collection.

I would really recommend [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), or making the entire method (or most of it) `synchronized`.